# Getting ConstraintViolationException when trying to use BindingResult in Spring Controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, bean-validation

I have and endpoint, where I validate received json document which contains collections of objects. I would like to only log these objects which don't pass a validation, when others i would like to store in db. Controller should return 200 OK in that situation. I was trying to use BindingResult object for this purpose. Unfortunately i always get a ConstraintViolationException. It seems that it validates it before it enter the method and throw exception. How can I force it to use BindingResult object ?

```
@RestController
@Validated
@RequestMapping(path = "/test")
class TestController {

    @PostMapping(consumes = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Void> addObjects(@RequestBody @Valid List<Document> objects, BindingResult bindingResult) {

        if(bindingResult.hasErrors()){

        }            
        return new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}
```

I'm using Spring Boot 1.5.9.RELEASE with Java 8

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to solve it finally. Problem is with @Validated annotation on controller class. With this annotation spring do a validation on request and throw ConstraintViolationException. Without that, validation is triggered later and it results are stored in BindingResult object as expected

Answer (score 0):

Could You please add the model classes with its annotations?
Remember that if You have any fields in `Document` class which are Your custom defined classes and You want it to be validated also then You have to decorate these fields with  `@Valid` annotation too.